# Regex in combination with jQuery text() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var regex1 = $('#element').text().match(/\b(06\d{8})\b/g);
   console.log('regex1: ' + regex1);
  
   var regex2 = $('#element').text().match(/(06\d{8})/g); 
   console.log('regex2: ' + regex2);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id = "element">
 0600000000
    0600000001
    <div>0600000002</div> 0600000003
    TEST:0600000004
    <span>0600000005</span><span>TEST0600000006</span><span>0600</span><span>000007</span>
  
</div>
```

What is want is only 6 matches 0600000000-0600000005. 
Looks great when I use this regex: `/\b(06\d{8})\b/g` https://regex101.com/r/fE6gJ7/1

But.., when I use the jQuery `text()` it looks like the output of `text()` replaces every HTML tag with "nothing":

Output `$(element).text()`

```
 0600000000
    0600000001
    0600000002 0600000003
    TEST:0600000004
    0600000005TEST06000000060600000007
```

Is it possible to avoid this? Or can I replace every HTML tag with a single space?
Or what is the alternative(iterate over all text elements?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.html()` insetad of `.text()`. `.text()` will remove the HTML tags inside the element and the textContent will be concatenated with other text.

So, using `text()` on the parent element for following

```
<span>0600000005</span><span>TEST0600000006</span><span>0600</span><span>000007</span>
```

will give

```
0600000005TEST06000000060600000007
```

And regex will not capture anything here because of word boundary.

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var regex1 = $('#element').html().match(/\b(06\d{8})\b/g);
   console.log('regex1: ' + regex1);
  
   var regex2 = $('#element').html().match(/(06\d{8})/g); 
   console.log('regex2: ' + regex2);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id = "element">
 0600000000
    0600000001
    <div>0600000002</div> 0600000003
    TEST:0600000004
    <span>0600000005</span><span>TEST0600000006</span><span>0600</span><span>000007</span>
  
</div>
```